# Flutter cli and very_good_cli gitignore leaves many unversioned files

Tags: flutter, dart, gitignore

I just created a project with very_good_cli, did a git init, and have 227 unversioned files. Likewise, I recently, within the past two weeks, created a new flutter project using flutter create and did a git init this morning.

After doing the git init, both projects had an abundance of unversioned files. The VGC version had over two hundred. The standard version had over 60 (after adding my project files to version control). I don't recall projects created earlier having anything like these numbers. I have compared my gitignore to those from earlier projects and see nothing obvious.

I would have thought both tools would create a .gitignore with all the appropriate files ignored. Maybe this mass of files should not be ignored? Are these .gitignore really complete and all these files should be checked in? Or, what is missing from my ignore files?

The .gitignore from the flutter created project is

```
*.class
*.lock
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/
.gitconfig

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/*

# Visual Studio Code related
.classpath
.project
.settings/
# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
.vscode/*
.history/*

# Flutter repo-specific
/bin/cache/
/bin/mingit/
/dev/benchmarks/mega_gallery/
/dev/bots/.recipe_deps
/dev/bots/android_tools/
/dev/docs/doc/
/dev/docs/flutter.docs.zip
/dev/docs/lib/
/dev/docs/pubspec.yaml
/dev/integration_tests/**/xcuserdata
/dev/integration_tests/**/Pods
/packages/flutter/coverage/
version

# packages file containing multi-root paths
.packages.generated

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
build/
flutter_*.png
linked_*.ds
unlinked.ds
unlinked_spec.ds
.fvm/

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Android Studio will place build artifacts here
/android/app/debug
/android/app/profile
/android/app/release

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
**/android/key.properties
**/android/.idea/
*.jks

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/ephemeral
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Coverage
coverage/

# Submodules
!pubspec.lock
packages/**/pubspec.lock

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Exceptions to the above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
!/dev/ci/**/Gemfile.lock
!.vscode/extensions.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.idea/codeStyles/
!.idea/dictionaries/
!.idea/runConfigurations/
```

The .gitignore in the Very Good Cli project is

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.lock
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/*

# Visual Studio Code related
.classpath
.project
.settings/
.vscode/*

# Flutter repo-specific
/bin/cache/
/bin/mingit/
/dev/benchmarks/mega_gallery/
/dev/bots/.recipe_deps
/dev/bots/android_tools/
/dev/docs/doc/
/dev/docs/flutter.docs.zip
/dev/docs/lib/
/dev/docs/pubspec.yaml
/dev/integration_tests/**/xcuserdata
/dev/integration_tests/**/Pods
/packages/flutter/coverage/
version

# packages file containing multi-root paths
.packages.generated

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
build/
flutter_*.png
linked_*.ds
unlinked.ds
unlinked_spec.ds
.fvm/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
**/android/key.properties
**/android/.idea/
*.jks

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Coverage
coverage/

# Submodules
!pubspec.lock
packages/**/pubspec.lock

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Exceptions to the above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
!/dev/ci/**/Gemfile.lock
!.vscode/extensions.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.idea/codeStyles/
!.idea/dictionaries/
!.idea/runConfigurations/
```

From the Flutter created version the unversioned files are:

1. <project_root>/android/.gitignore
2. <project_root>/ios/.gitignore
3. <project_root>/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
4. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
5. <project_root>/android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml
6. <project_root>/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift
7. <project_root>/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist
8. <project_root>/android/app/build.gradle
9. <project_root>/android/build.gradle
10. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json
11. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/Contents.json
12. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
13. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
14. <project_root>/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig
15. <project_root>/web/favicon.png
16. <project_root>/android/gradle.properties
17. <project_root>/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
18. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
19. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
20. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
21. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
22. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
23. <project_root>/web/icons/Icon-192.png
24. <project_root>/web/icons/Icon-512.png
25. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@1x.png
26. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@2x.png
27. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@3x.png
28. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@1x.png
29. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@2x.png
30. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@3x.png
31. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@1x.png
32. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@2x.png
33. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@3x.png
34. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-60x60@2x.png
35. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-60x60@3x.png
36. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-76x76@1x.png
37. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-76x76@2x.png
38. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png
39. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.png
40. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist
41. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist
42. <project_root>/web/index.html
43. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Info.plist
44. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml
45. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml
46. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage.png
47. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@2x.png
48. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@3x.png
49. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard
50. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
51. <project_root>/.idea/runConfigurations/main_dart.xml
52. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/cosmic_instant/MainActivity.kt
53. <project_root>/web/manifest.json
54. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
55. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/README.md
56. <project_root>/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig
57. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/Runner.xcscheme
58. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h
59. <project_root>/android/settings.gradle
60. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
61. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml
62. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
63. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings

The unversioned files in the Very Good Cli generated project are:

1. <project_root>/android/.gitignore
2. <project_root>/ios/.gitignore
3. <project_root>/.gitignore
4. <project_root>/.metadata
5. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/16.png
6. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/16.png
7. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/16.png
8. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/20.png
9. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/20.png
10. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/20.png
11. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/29.png
12. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/29.png
13. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/29.png
14. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/32.png
15. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/32.png
16. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/32.png
17. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/40.png
18. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/40.png
19. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/40.png
20. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/48.png
21. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/48.png
22. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/48.png
23. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/50.png
24. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/50.png
25. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/50.png
26. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/55.png
27. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/55.png
28. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/55.png
29. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/57.png
30. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/57.png
31. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/57.png
32. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/58.png
33. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/58.png
34. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/58.png
35. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/60.png
36. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/60.png
37. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/60.png
38. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/64.png
39. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/64.png
40. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/64.png
41. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/72.png
42. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/72.png
43. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/72.png
44. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/76.png
45. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/76.png
46. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/76.png
47. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/80.png
48. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/80.png
49. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/80.png
50. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/87.png
51. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/87.png
52. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/87.png
53. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/88.png
54. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/88.png
55. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/88.png
56. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/100.png
57. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/100.png
58. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/100.png
59. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/114.png
60. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/114.png
61. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/114.png
62. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/120.png
63. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/120.png
64. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/120.png
65. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/128.png
66. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/128.png
67. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/128.png
68. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/144.png
69. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/144.png
70. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/144.png
71. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/152.png
72. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/152.png
73. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/152.png
74. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/167.png
75. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/167.png
76. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/167.png
77. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/172.png
78. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/172.png
79. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/172.png
80. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/180.png
81. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/180.png
82. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/180.png
83. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/196.png
84. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/196.png
85. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/196.png
86. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/216.png
87. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/216.png
88. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/216.png
89. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/256.png
90. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/256.png
91. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/256.png
92. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/512.png
93. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/512.png
94. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/512.png
95. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/1024.png
96. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/1024.png
97. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/1024.png
98. <project_root>/analysis_options.yaml
99. <project_root>/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
100. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
101. <project_root>/android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml
102. <project_root>/lib/app/app.dart
103. <project_root>/lib/app/app_bloc_observer.dart
104. <project_root>/lib/l10n/arb/app_en.arb
105. <project_root>/lib/l10n/arb/app_es.arb
106. <project_root>/test/app_test.dart
107. <project_root>/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift
108. <project_root>/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist
109. <project_root>/android/app/build.gradle
110. <project_root>/android/build.gradle
111. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json
112. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-dev.appiconset/Contents.json
113. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-stg.appiconset/Contents.json
114. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/Contents.json
115. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/Contents.json
116. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
117. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
118. <project_root>/lib/counter/counter.dart
119. <project_root>/lib/counter/cubit/counter_cubit.dart
120. <project_root>/test/counter/cubit/counter_cubit_test.dart
121. <project_root>/lib/counter/view/counter_page.dart
122. <project_root>/test/counter/view/counter_page_test.dart
123. <project_root>/coverage_badge.svg
124. <project_root>/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig
125. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/development.xcscheme
126. <project_root>/.idea/runConfigurations/development.xml
127. <project_root>/.vscode/extensions.json
128. <project_root>/web/icons/favicon.png
129. <project_root>/web/favicon.png
130. <project_root>/android/gradle.properties
131. <project_root>/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
132. <project_root>/test/helpers/helpers.dart
133. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/drawable/ic_launch_image.xml
134. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launch_image.xml
135. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
136. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
137. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
138. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
139. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
140. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
141. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
142. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
143. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
144. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
145. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
146. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
147. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
148. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
149. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
150. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
151. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
152. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
153. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/ic_launcher-playstore.png
154. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/ic_launcher-playstore.png
155. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/ic_launcher-playstore.png
156. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml
157. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/values/ic_launcher_background.xml
158. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml
159. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/values/ic_launcher_background.xml
160. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml
161. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml
162. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml
163. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml
164. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
165. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
166. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
167. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
168. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
169. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
170. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
171. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
172. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
173. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
174. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
175. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
176. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
177. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
178. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png
179. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml
180. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml
181. <project_root>/android/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml
182. <project_root>/web/icons/Icon-192.png
183. <project_root>/web/icons/Icon-512.png
184. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist
185. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist
186. <project_root>/web/index.html
187. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Info.plist
188. <project_root>/lib/l10n/l10n.dart
189. <project_root>/l10n.yaml
190. <project_root>/.vscode/launch.json
191. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/drawable/launch_background.xml
192. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml
193. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml
194. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml
195. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@1x.png
196. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@2x.png
197. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@3x.png
198. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard
199. <project_root>/LICENSE
200. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
201. <project_root>/.github/workflows/main.yaml
202. <project_root>/lib/main_development.dart
203. <project_root>/lib/main_production.dart
204. <project_root>/lib/main_staging.dart
205. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/verygoodcore/MainActivity.kt
206. <project_root>/web/manifest.json
207. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/production.xcscheme
208. <project_root>/.idea/runConfigurations/production.xml
209. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
210. <project_root>/pubspec.lock
211. <project_root>/pubspec.yaml
212. <project_root>/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
213. <project_root>/test/helpers/pump_app.dart
214. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/README.md
215. <project_root>/README.md
216. <project_root>/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig
217. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/Runner.xcscheme
218. <project_root>/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h
219. <project_root>/android/settings.gradle
220. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/staging.xcscheme
221. <project_root>/.idea/runConfigurations/staging.xml
222. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/values/styles.xml
223. <project_root>/android/app/src/development/res/values-night/styles.xml
224. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
225. <project_root>/android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml
226. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
227. <project_root>/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings

Comment: All we can tell you from the `git` side of things is that files you list as ignored will, as long as they're not already in the staging area, not be added *to* the staging area. Which files *should* never be added to the staging area is not a Git question. I have no idea which files should be managed and which not, here.

Comment: I didn't see this as a git issue, rather a flutter and very_good_cli issue. I will change the tags. I am guessing that it is alright to include/commit all that stuff. I am just surprised.